# What is necessary to update the Raspberry PI firmware on a system running Ubuntu 22.04 arm64 on a Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB

Tags: upgrade, firmware

I have a feeling many will believe this answer is obvious; I am reaching the conclusion that the following will probably get the Raspberry Pi firmware update done for Ubuntu 22.04.  Even moreso when I read Raspberry Pi firmware is in the vfat boot partition for both the RasPI OS and Ubuntu recognizing it has a different mountpoint in the respective OS.

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

I know rpi-update is "bleeding edge" and generally not what I want. It is only intended for the RasPI OS with warnings about compatibility with other OSes another reason not to use it.

The only askUbuntu content was about trying to get Ubuntu releases for RasPI2/3 to run on RasPI4; should not be an issue for Ubuntu 22.04 that actually supports the RasPI 4, if as I now suspect upgrade alters the boot partition as required for each change.

If it matters the Uboot loader is compatible with Ubuntu 22.04 as I have booted it from a flash drive attached to a USB port.  I checked several months ago and my PIs had the current uboot eeprom then.

Thanks

Comment: My Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB has been running Ubuntu 21.10 since new. Lately It has been asking me to upgrade to 22.04 after booting. I have not had much luck with 22.04 on some older computers. I will follow this thread.

Answer (score 0):

**A "brief" forewarning: running EEPROM updates can include risks all the way to bricking your Raspberry Pi 4B, therefor I must emphasize that trying out anything mentioned in this reply is DOING SO AT YOUR OWN RISK. ALWAYS MAKE A BACKUP COPY OF YOUR EXISTING SYSTEM BEFORE ATTEMPTING AN EEPROM FLASH UPDATE. Especially a copy of the boot partition, which is quite easy (and small in file size) to backup to another computer by simply copying all files and directories that are inside the boot partition.**

As of [Raspberry Pi-4 firmware upgrade (eeprom), over UBUNTU 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253070/raspberry-pi-4-firmware-upgrade-eeprom-over-ubuntu-20-04) it seems that only

```
sudo apt install -y libraspberrypi0 libraspberrypi-bin
```

is necessary prior to

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:waveform/eeprom
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rpi-eeprom -y
sudo reboot
```

that may help you, but read disclaimer at start and linked reference.